# WPF Single Selection Across Multiple ItemsControls

Tags: wpf, selection, itemscontrol

Part of my app has a month-view calendar interface, but I'm having trouble with item selection.  The interface is set up so that each of the days in the view contains a `ListBox` of items, much like the month view in Outlook.  The problem I'm experiencing is that I need to maintain a single item selection across all of the `ListBox`es.

Below is a sample that should adequately describe my situation.  I need to maintain a single selection between both `ListBox`es.

```
<Window x:Class="StackOverflow.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition />
            <ColumnDefinition />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding Numbers}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject"/>
        <ListBox Grid.Column="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Dates}"
                 SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedObject"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And the view model for the window:

```
class MainWindowViewModel : DependencyObject
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty SelectedObjectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("SelectedObject", typeof(object),
                                    typeof(MainWindowViewModel),
                                    new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

    public ObservableCollection<int> Numbers { get; set; }
    public ObservableCollection<DateTime> Dates { get; set; }
    public object SelectedObject
    {
        get { return GetValue(SelectedObjectProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedObjectProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

In this primitive example, I would expect that when the SelectedObject property of my view model gets set to an item that's not in one `ListBox`, the selection would be removed in that `ListBox`, but that doesn't happen.  I understand that I can simply name each ListBox, and hook into the SelectionChanged event.  I'd prefer to not have to do that with an entire month-view calendar.  There *has* to be a better way.

In a previous iteration of the app, I was able to create a SelectionManager static class with an attached property that was used to maintain selection.  However, I can't use this now as the classes I'm using for my items are not `DependencyObject`s, and I'd really prefer not to have to create `DependencyObject` wrapper classes as this will considerably complicate my architecture.

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**  Added a view model class as requested.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by creating a separate selection manager class and an ISelectable interface.  You can read about the details on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/471825/Single-Selection-Across-Multiple-ItemsControls).

Answer (score 1):

Bind both `ListBoxes` to the same collection (make an observable collection of `DatesAndNumber` objects or something along those lines) and use converters and/or data templates to get the desired output. Then you can simply set `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem` to true on both `ListBoxes` to get the desired effect.
Reference: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.issynchronizedwithcurrentitem.aspx

Comment: My main window view model does have a central collection of items, but each day filters to its own collection based on the date.  Maybe if you can show a simple way for each day to bind to the central collection while filtering out the unneeded items...

Comment: could you provide your view model code? I'll take a look at it tomorrow and get back to you.

Comment: could you please provide some more sample code so as to replicate your scenario

Answer (score 0):

how about using ICollectionView and its associated filter ?

here is a link which explains it better

http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/11/22/icollectionview-explained/

Comment: Good idea, but it appears that adding a filter (e.g. to show only the items for a given day) will apply that filter everywhere that the `ICollectionView` is used.  This means that I would still have to have separate `ICollectionView`s for each day, and I lose the selection tracking features.